# Shell very slow to load - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

Opening my terminal (ctrl+alt+t), it takes a long time to load my prompt. I had read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339499/bash-taking-a-lot-of-time-to-load) regarding the same issue but none of their solutions helped me. On opening the terminal, it takes around 4-5 seconds to load and just before the prompt appears, I see a really quick flash of a white splash-screen sort of program popping up. I don't think that this has happened after installing any particular package/software. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014823/how-to-profile-a-bash-shell-script-slow-startup

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To see every command that runs during your shell's startup configuration, put

```
set -x
```

at the top and

```
set +x
```

at the bottom of both files `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`.

(Keep your text editor open so you can undo these changes easily!)

Then in a terminal, run:

```bsh
$ bash --login
```

and see which command takes the most time.

Comment: I may be super stupid but I cannot figure out how this works. I added those lines but nothing changed at all.

Comment: @UpmostScarab After adding the lines, type `bash --login` in a terminal, and see what happens. (Press Ctrl-D afterwards to exit the shell you just started.)

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that my terminal was suppressing the output.

Comment: Thanks `SDKMAN!` for slowing down my work.

Comment: same for me... was SDKMAN (http://sdkman.io/)... timeout connection was causing the shell to take over 10s to load T_T

Comment: virtualenvwrapper was the culprit in my case. I `apt purge` ed it

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18.04 and in my case `curl --silent --location --connect-timeout 7 --max-time 10 https://api.sdkman.io/1/candidates/app/cliversion` is causing the delay. Can anybody please guide me on how to fix the delay?

Comment: @JigneshGohel I don't use sdkman myself but it looks like you might be able to set [`sdkman_curl_connect_timeout=2`](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/blob/21e1e73174600f3f2e36624e20421a8e9ee47d04/src/main/bash/sdkman-utils.sh#L67-L69) to make it fail more quickly. Here is the [issue](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/586) for your problem. You could also try opening a fresh StackOverflow or AskUbuntu question tagged "sdkman". (If your version of sdkman is very old, you may want to clear it from your bashrc, and install the latest version.)

Comment: @joeytwiddle Thanks. I have `SDKMAN 5.1.4+78` which looks like an older version compared to the recent release shown at https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/releases/tag/5.7.3? Does it mean that I should manually upgrade the version on my machine and the problem should be fixed?

Comment: @JigneshGohel If that `curl` command is code inside SDKMan (not inside your bashrc) then I guess a simple upgrade might help. No need to clear the bashrc.

Comment: If you're suspicious about SDKMAN! executing `sdk selfupdate` may solve the terminal slowness problem as it did in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a really peculiar example, that I want to share with you. Namely, I had this command in my `.profile` and `.bash_profile` file:

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.profile
```

and in `.bashrc` file:

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

that I pasted in my config files instead of in my shell.

Therefore, each time I logged in to my shell, it appended new instructions to the config files, creating this infinitely increasing loop of new, useless instructions.

Hopefully, my silly wrong copy-and-pasting story may gave you a little smile :D