# Ubuntu terminal taking a very long time, because of import 'keras'

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, gnome-terminal, ssd, tensorflow

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows dual boot on my SSD. And HDD is common to both, for storage. 
Now the problem is that the terminal takes a very very long time to open when run from hdd, but opens up quickly when done from ssd. If opened from ssd, I can easily cd to hdd, no problem in that. But I can't open terminal directly from any folder in hdd, it takes longer if I open it from a long path (deeper into directories).

Following answer from https://askubuntu.com/a/717989/635307. I added `set -x` and `set +x` at the beginning and end of `.bashrc` and `.profile`. Now when running from hdd it stucks at the following lines:

```
+++ . /home/easy/anaconda3/etc/conda/activate.d/keras_activate.sh
+++++ python /home/easy/anaconda3/etc/keras/load_config.py
++++ KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
++++ python -c 'import keras'
```

For reference, here are the same lines when I open terminal from ssd:

```
+++ . /home/easy/anaconda3/etc/conda/activate.d/keras_activate.sh
+++++ python /home/easy/anaconda3/etc/keras/load_config.py
++++ KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
++++ python -c 'import keras'
++ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
++ __conda_hashr
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ '[' -n '' ']'
++ hash -r
+ unset __conda_setup
+ PATH=/home/easy/anaconda3/bin:/home/easy/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/mnt/hdd/MATLAB_linux/bin
+ set +x
```

I have very less idea about how all this works. Is there any way I can speed up the terminal opening time when opened from hdd? Thanks.

Comment: I wonder what you did to fix it. I removed the conda activation from the .bashrc file to avoid this issue. This way conda will not activate base for you automatically , you can always choose to activate if required by `conda activate base`