# Ubuntu 20.04 shell loads slow because of "npm config --loglevel=warn get prefix" command

Tags: command-line, bash, npm

My shell always takes a couple of seconds to load the first time when I boot up, after boot up, when I open up the terminal multiple times to load the shell again and again the boot time decreases to around 1.5 second.

Upon following the advice of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/717989/834982) on another question relating to slow loading of shell.

I found that `npm config --loglevel=warn get prefix` **takes the longest time always**, rest commands load instantaneously every time.

I was not able to find some pointers on the net and hence I asked here.

My npm version is 6.12.0

I realize this comes when bash loads the `nvm.sh` script, but how can this be made faster, if at all?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but then I noticed the actual problem was with the `nvm` being loaded during the bash startup in the `.bashrc`, please check if you have these lines in your `.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

If you do have these lines in your `.bashrc` please add the `--no-use` flag like this:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" --no-use  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

This basically doesn't make it run on the initialization of your bash session and you would be able to use `nvm` as usual, you're just skipping it being loaded when your bash session starts.

I went from **6 seconds** of waiting for bash to load up to just **0.1 seconds**.