# Terminal Shell Doesn't Work

Tags: command-line

A few days ago my shell in the terminal just wouldn't load. I had to use Visual Studio   Code's terminal to do everything. I tried shutting Linux down. I had tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717961/shell-very-slow-to-load-ubuntu-14-04), nevertheless it didn't work. Thanks in advance. If you need any further information, please tell me.

Comment: Do you know what terminal app you're using regularly? If you try to launch -that- program from the VS code terminal, what happens? Hopefully it spits out a useful error message, which you obviously aren't getting when looking running it from the UI. There's a chance it's logging a good error message to one of the logs in /var/log, or to a console, like tty1-tty8.

Comment: I'm using the built-in terminal.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling should I just reinstall the entire system?

Comment: That is up to you. If you've customized it a lot, and have lots of data on it, and other users share it, perhaps not. If you've only been using it for a short amount of time, and you really haven't spent much time setting things up for you, you might want to consider it. Is the time to troubleshoot going to exceed the time to backup, reinstall, and restore...?

Comment: I already reinstalled it. I'm still having the problem. I haven't installed anything.

Comment: Not sure what default terminal is. If it's gnome, it'll be gnome-terminal. If KDE, likely konsole. I'd try running that program from the VS Code terminal, and see what errors it reports.

Comment: running what program?

Comment: @NotDiamondZ so the terminal window is opening, but you don't get a shell prompt inside it, correct? That is often because of an error in your shell initialization files (such as a file that sources itself, leading to an infinite loop). If you reinstalled the system but preserved your home directory that might explain why the problem remained.

Comment: Yeah. That's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a update and that was what was preventing the Shell from loading.